# Polygonization of disjoint segments

Tags: python, image-processing, geometry

The problem is the following: I got a png file :
[example.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KjR3.png)

- that I filter using chan vese of `skimage.segmentation.chan_vese`

  - It's return a png file in black and white.
- i detect segments around my new png file with `cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector()`

  - it's return a list a segment

But the list of segments represent disjoint segments.

I use two naive methods to polygonize this list of segment:

-It's seems that `cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector()` create a almost continuous list so I just join by creating new segments:

```py
import import skimage.segmentation as seg
import  skimage.filters as filters 
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageOps
import numpy as np
from skimage import data, img_as_float
import cv2 as cv2

points =Image.open(png_file)
points = ImageOps.grayscale(points)
points = np.asarray(points)
image_gray = points
points = img_as_float(points)
points = seg.chan_vese(points, mu=0.01, lambda1=2, lambda2=1, tol=1e-10, max_iter=2000,init_level_set="checkerboard")
print("seg done")
Image.fromarray(points).save("chan_vese.png")
```

the output is [output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDNG4.png)

```py
points =Image.open("chan_vese.png")
points = ImageOps.grayscale(points)
points = np.asarray(points)
#Create default parametrization LSD
lsd = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector()
#Detect lines in the image
lines = lsd.detect(points)
#Draw detected lines in the image
drawn_img = lsd.drawSegments(image_gray,lines)
#Show image
Image.fromarray(drawn_img).save(output_png) 
#we got the segments now, but they are disjoints
```

I got this image with segment on it to have an idea: [output_segments.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaXEE.png)

```
list_segment = []
for segment in self.lines:
     list_segment.append(segment[0])

new_lines = []
for i, segment in enumerate(list_segment):
     if i < len(list_segment)-1:
            new_lines.append([[list_segment[i][2], list_segment[i][3], list_segment[i+1][0], list_segment[i+1][1]]])
     else: 
            new_lines.append([[list_segment[i][2], list_segment[i][3], list_segment[0][2], list_segment[0][3]]])
```

But the list isn't continuous so I got some artefacts of kind
I got this output: [output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEC82.png)

- The second one is to take the closest one in norm2:

```
        for i, segment in enumerate(list_segment):
            new_lines.append([segment])
            dist_min = float("inf")
            for j , segment2 in enumerate(list_segment):
                if np.array_equal(segment, segment2):
                    distance1 = calcul_distance_points(segment[2], segment[3], segment2[0], segment2[1])
                    if distance1 < dist_min:
                        dist_min = distance1
                        new_lines.append(([[segment[0], segment[1], list_segment[j][0], list_segment[j][1]]]))
```

The problem of this method is that I can jump edges.

I find this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07019.pdf) with kind respond to my problem but I look for a simple way to solve.

Do you got any suggestion to do this, and avoid this potential jump ?

PS: The purpose of this algo, is at the end create a mask with this polygon.

Comment: Please share your input images and your intermediate and final results so we can see what you are referring to. Also, try to ensure your code is runnable - with `import` statements etc.

Comment: i edited new things I hope this will improve your comprehension of my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I use another library to solve this problem: `OpenCV-python`

We got have also the detection of segments( which are not disjoint) but with a hierarchy with the function `findContours`. The hierarchy is useful since the function detects different polygons. This implies no problems of connections we could have with the other method like explain in the post

Comment: I think if you want to create a polygon with disjoint segments you need to implement the paper (link in the post). I would be very interested in this if you do this by intellectual curiosity